# TinyMCE 4 Editor and IE - unclickable content area when tables are added

Tags: internet-explorer, tinymce

Ran into a very similar issue [here](http://www.tinymce.com/develop/bugtracker_view.php?id=7087).

On IE-11, when either loading existing content that has a table element or adding a table via the wysiwyg, the content area in the editor may become non clickable and the user can't add more content after the table.

Answer (score 0):

On editor instance initialization, add a callback via init_instance_callback to add a `<br>` tag with the data attribute `data-mce-bogus="1"` to enable the bottom of the editor to be clickable.  I used jQuery to make that happen.

```
function initCallback(tmceInstance) {
    jQuery(tmceInstance.getBody()).append('<br data-mce-bogus="1">');
}

tinyMCE.init({
    ...
    init_instance_callback : "initCallback",
});
```